# Типизация "**kwargs" в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы, typing

Как аннотировать тип `**kwargs`?

В python можно указать тип используя [Unpack](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/#rationale),
такой подход требует определения класса наследуемого от `TypedDict`:

```py
class Kwargs(TypedDict):
    foo: Any
    bar: Any

def some(**kwargs: Unpack[Kwargs]) -> None:
    pass

some(foo=1, bar=2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... но параметрами являются ключевые слова определенные в `enum`:

```py
@enum.unique
class RecordKey(enum.StrEnum):
    foo = "foo"
    bar = "bar"
```

... а значения всегда один и тот же тип. Как можно добиться такого результата?:

```py
def some(**kwargs: Unpack[dict[RecordKey, MyClass]])
```

В `enum.StrEnum` может быть не 2-3, а сотня ключевых слов. ... и этот тип применяется в других местах приложения.